# Dedicated server: after how many years should I upgrade to a new one, even if I don't need new hardware?

Tags: dedicated-server

There is a higher probability that the old hardware will die, so after how many years do you suggest I rent a new server and abandon the old one?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to ALWAYS have a hardware warranty support for a server in production.

For that matter it depend on the manufacturer, some offer over 7 years of warranty, so the time is dependant on the warranty support you have.